# how to send a payment transaction using web3js... and fetch contract address dynamically using web3js without hardcoding in app.js

Tags: web3js, payments

```
function sendPayment(uint orderNumber) public payable{
   //restricting only buyer of partitcular order can make payments
   require(Orders[orderNumber].buyerAddress==msg.sender);

    //checking whether amount=totalPrice
    require(Orders[orderNumber].totalPrice==msg.value);

}
```

Comment: "without hardcoding in app.js"? Well where exactly is that app.js of yours, which is supposed to send a payment transaction to a hard-coded address??? In other words, show the code that you want help with, and explain what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XT2Pnm6E  this is my solidity code , in this i need to call sendPayment function using web3js....  and also how to capture the events generated

Comment: Post it here please (only the part which is relevant to your question).

Comment: yeah i changed the code and this is the function i dont know how to call using web3js...